# is it possible to train sapi in C#?

Tags: c#, sapi

is it possible to train sapi with C#? lets say I have a wav file contains a specific word the engine is not able to detect it or it detects the word but it gives wrong value.. so I need to add this word with its text to the dictionary is that possible?

thanks,

Answer (score 1):

It's certainly possible to train SAPI using C#.  It's not trivially easy (nor is it trivially easy in C++).  Look at the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/299799/acoustic-training-using-sapi-5-3-speech-api) to see how to do it; then you can use the speechlib wrappers around SAPI to access the training mode APIs from C#.