# Custom training phrase for Windows 7 speech recognition?

Tags: customization, speech-recognition

Windows 7 speech recognition requires speaking the following training phrase before it can be enabled:
"Peter dictates to his computer. He prefers it to typing, and particularly prefers it to pen and paper."

I want to use Windows speech recognition to batch process a large number of MP3 files of lectures by a single individual. So what I would like to do is pick a similar phrase from these pre-existing dictations and use the phrase I choose to train it, instead of the built-in training phrase.

Mainly because I don't have a recording of the speaker saying "Peter dictates to his computer. He prefers it to typing, and particularly prefers it to pen and paper." but I have 50 hours of him saying lots of other things.

Is this possible?

Answer (score -1):

use the api for the speech recognition tool, the person in [Acoustic training using SAPI 5.3 Speech API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/299799/acoustic-training-using-sapi-5-3-speech-api) had the same question as you, probably

Comment: Sorry if this is perceived as a duplicate question - I wouldn't even know what to search for to find that particular answer. Can this api be downloaded and included in VB.net code without too much trouble? I'm not much of a programmer but I can research and do a little programming if this has a decent chance of actually working.