# How to programmatically train the SpeechRecognitionEngine and convert audio file to text in C# or vb.net

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, speech-recognition

Is it possible to programmatically train the recognizer giving .wavs instead of talking to a microphone?

If so, How to do it?, currently I have the code that performs recognition on the audio in a **0.wav** file and writes the recognized text to the console.

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Speech.Recognition
Imports System.Speech.AudioFormat

Namespace SampleRecognition
    Class Program
        Shared completed As Boolean

        Public Shared Sub Main(ByVal args As String())
            Using recognizer As New SpeechRecognitionEngine()
                Dim dictation As Grammar = New DictationGrammar()
                dictation.Name = "Dictation Grammar"
                recognizer.LoadGrammar(dictation)
                ' Configure the input to the recognizer.
                recognizer.SetInputToWaveFile("C:\Users\ME\v02\0.wav")

                ' Attach event handlers for the results of recognition.
                AddHandler recognizer.SpeechRecognized, AddressOf recognizer_SpeechRecognized
                AddHandler recognizer.RecognizeCompleted, AddressOf recognizer_RecognizeCompleted

                ' Perform recognition on the entire file.
                Console.WriteLine("Starting asynchronous recognition...")
                completed = False
                recognizer.RecognizeAsync()
                ' Keep the console window open.
                While Not completed
                    Console.ReadLine()
                End While
                Console.WriteLine("Done.")
            End Using

            Console.WriteLine()
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit...")
            Console.ReadKey()
        End Sub

        ' Handle the SpeechRecognized event.
        Private Shared Sub recognizer_SpeechRecognized(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As SpeechRecognizedEventArgs)
            If e.Result IsNot Nothing AndAlso e.Result.Text IsNot Nothing Then
                Console.WriteLine("  Recognized text =  {0}", e.Result.Text)
            Else
                Console.WriteLine("  Recognized text not available.")
            End If
        End Sub

        ' Handle the RecognizeCompleted event.
        Private Shared Sub recognizer_RecognizeCompleted(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As RecognizeCompletedEventArgs)
            If e.[Error] IsNot Nothing Then
                Console.WriteLine("  Error encountered, {0}: {1}", e.[Error].[GetType]().Name, e.[Error].Message)
            End If
            If e.Cancelled Then
                Console.WriteLine("  Operation cancelled.")
            End If
            If e.InputStreamEnded Then
                Console.WriteLine("  End of stream encountered.")
            End If
            completed = True
        End Sub
    End Class
End Namespace
```

## EDIT

I understand using the Training wizard is useful to do this

> accomplished by Opening Speech Recognition,clicking Start
>   button->Control Panel->Ease of Access->Speech Recognition

.

How to custom train the speech recognition with custom wav or even mp3 files?

When using Training wizard (Control Panel training UI) training files are stored in 
**{AppData}\Local\Microsoft\Speech\Files\TrainingAudio**.

How can I use or make a custom training instead of using Training wizard?

The Speech Control Panel creates registry entries for the training audio files in the key **HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Speech\RecoProfiles\Tokens{ProfileGUID}{00000000-0000-0000-0000-0000000000000000}\Files**

Do the registry entries created by code have to be placed in there?

The reason to do this is I want to custom train with my own wav files and list of words and phrases,  then transfer all to other systems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can generate custom training using SAPI engine (not the managed api)

Here's a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/299799/acoustic-training-using-sapi-5-3-speech-api) on how to do it (though a bit vague)

Answer (score 5):

It's certainly possible to train SAPI using C#. you can use the speechlib wrappers around SAPI to access the training mode APIs from C#.here [@Eric Brown answered the procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/299799/acoustic-training-using-sapi-5-3-speech-api)

- Create an inproc recognizer & bind the appropriate audio input.
- Ensure that you’re retaining the audio for your recognitions; you’ll need it later.
- Create a grammar containing the text to train.
- Set the grammar’s state to pause the recognizer when a recognition occurs. (This helps with training from an audio file, as well.)

  When a recognition occurs:
- Get the recognized text and the retained audio.
- Create a stream object using CoCreateInstance(CLSID_SpStream).
- Create a training audio file using ISpRecognizer::GetObjectToken , and    ISpObjectToken::GetStorageFileName  , and bind it to the stream (using ISpStream::BindToFile ).
- Copy the retained audio into the stream object.
- QI the stream object for the ISpTranscript  interface, and use ISpTranscript::AppendTranscript  to add the recognized text to the stream.
- Update the grammar for the next utterance, resume the recognizer, and repeat until you’re out of training text.

Other option could be training the sapi once with desired output, then get profiles with code and transport that to other systems, the following code Returns An ISpeechObjectTokens object.:

> The GetProfiles method returns a selection of the available user
>   speech profiles. Profiles are stored in the speech configuration
>   database as a series of tokens, with each token representing one
>   profile. GetProfiles retrieves all available profile tokens. The
>   returned list is an ISpeechObjectTokens object. Additional or more
>   detailed information about the tokens is available in methods
>   associated with ISpeechObjectTokens. The token search may be further
>   refined using the RequiredAttributes and OptionalAttributes search
>   attributes. Only tokens matching the specified RequiredAttributes
>   search attributes are returned. Of those tokens matching the
>   RequiredAttributes key, OptionalAttributes lists devices in the order
>   matching OptionalAttributes. If no search attributes are offered, all
>   tokens are returned. If no audio devices match the criteria,
>   GetAudioInputs returns an empty selection, that is, an
>   ISpeechObjectTokens collection with an ISpeechObjectTokens::Count
>   property of zero. [See Object Tokens and Registry Settings White Paper
>   for a list of SAPI 5-defined attributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee125457%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

```
Public SharedRecognizer As SpSharedRecognizer
Public theRecognizers As ISpeechObjectTokens

Private Sub Command1_Click()
    On Error GoTo EH

    Dim currentProfile As SpObjectToken
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim T As String
    Dim TokenObject As ISpeechObjectToken
    Set currentProfile = SharedRecognizer.Profile

    For i = 0 To theRecognizers.Count - 1
        Set TokenObject = theRecognizers.Item(i)

        If tokenObject.Id <> currentProfile.Id Then
            Set SharedRecognizer.Profile = TokenObject
            T = "New Profile installed: "
            T = T & SharedRecognizer.Profile.GetDescription
            Exit For
        Else
            T = "No new profile has been installed."
        End If
    Next i

    MsgBox T, vbInformation

EH:
    If Err.Number Then ShowErrMsg
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Load()
    On Error GoTo EH

    Const NL = vbNewLine
    Dim i, idPosition As Long
    Dim T As String
    Dim TokenObject As SpObjectToken

    Set SharedRecognizer = CreateObject("SAPI.SpSharedRecognizer")
    Set theRecognizers = SharedRecognizer.GetProfiles

    For i = 0 To theRecognizers.Count - 1
        Set TokenObject = theRecognizers.Item(i)
        T = T & TokenObject.GetDescription & "--" & NL & NL
        idPosition = InStrRev(TokenObject.Id, "\")
        T = T & Mid(TokenObject.Id, idPosition + 1) & NL
    Next i

    MsgBox T, vbInformation

EH:
    If Err.Number Then ShowErrMsg
End Sub

Private Sub ShowErrMsg()

    ' Declare identifiers:
    Dim T As String

    T = "Desc: " & Err.Description & vbNewLine
    T = T & "Err #: " & Err.Number
    MsgBox T, vbExclamation, "Run-Time Error"
    End

End Sub
```